# Intuition for $\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$

Tags: trigonometry, intuition

I understand how to prove that using the definitions of the elementary trig functions:

$$\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \frac{\dfrac{opp}{hyp}}{\dfrac{adj}{hyp}} = \frac{opp}{adj} = \tan\theta$$

However, I have a hard time visualizing that identity. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: You define the sinus, then you define the cosinus and you Call Tangent $\frac{\sin}{\cos}$.

Comment: ... or define tangent in the same way you define sin and cos, i.e. sin = opp/hyp, cos = adj/hyp, and tan = opp/adj

Answer (score 2):

There is a very nice way to visualize these functions. First, you need to draw the unit circle and pick some point on it. $\theta$ will be the angle between the point (1,0) anti-clockwise towards the point you chose. Then $\cos\theta$ is the $x$-coordinate and $\sin\theta$ is the $y$-coordinate of the point. Now, draw the vertical line to the $x$-axis going trough the point $(1,0)$. Moreover, draw the line going through your point and the origin. Mark the intersection of this line and the vertical line you drew before. The $y$-coordinate of this point is $\tan\theta$. That also tells you what happens when $\theta$ approaches $90$ degrees or $270$ degrees! Try to understand why this is true! If you have more questions about it, write a comment.

Comment: I can't really understand why that y-coordinate will be $tan\theta$... However, I found my question is answered by the information you provided before that: x and y coordinate of a point corresponds to its $cos\theta$ and $sin\theta$. Since $tan\theta=\frac{opp}{adj}$, $tan\theta=\frac{sin\theta}{cos\theta}$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Here, you find a picture of it: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Tangent-unit-circle.svg/1024px-Tangent-unit-circle.svg.png

As you just said, this is why $\tan\theta = \sin\theta/\cos\theta$. And you can get the representation with vertical line via the Theorem of Thales. Indeed if you draw the two triangles, you will see that two sides are parallel. If you take the notation from the picture, Thales tells you that $\tan\theta = QP/ OP$, where $O$ is the origin. But since $OP = 1$, you get that $\tan\theta$ is the $y$-coordinate of $Q$.

Comment: Is it possible to show me where the vertical line to the x-axis going through the point (1,0) is? I think I may misunderstand this part.

Comment: That is the line going through Q and P in the picture. $P$ is the point $(1,0)$. Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: There isn't a Q in that picture though, so I'm not sure what you are referring to... Furthermore, doesn't Thales involve the diameter of a circle? However, in trigonometry, the created triangle only has the radius of the circle.

Comment: I am sorry, in English it is called "intercept theorem"... Coming from a different culture ^^ And there is a Q in the top right corner of the triangle.

Comment: I understand now! The major problem was that the link you posted opens up the picture on a black background. As the picture has a transparent background, all the black words on it cannot be seen. But I solved this issue by copying and pasting the image onto a word doc! I still found my own explanation in the first comment better as it also explains why the identity is like that, maybe it just suits my way of thinking a little more haha. Still, it's enlightening to see the relationships from the perspective outlined in your answer - I'm pretty sure I wouldn't notice it myself! Thanks for that!

Comment: Perfect. Anyway, it is always better to come up with your own way